# A map functions? don't understand this dart

Tags: dart

I see this source from google_fonts of dart pub. It seems we have a function map? and asMap() has a arrow function? Don't understand this.

```dart
static Map<
      String,
      TextStyle Function({
    TextStyle? textStyle,
    Color? color,
    Color? backgroundColor,
    double? fontSize,
    FontWeight? fontWeight,
    FontStyle? fontStyle,
    double? letterSpacing,
    double? wordSpacing,
    TextBaseline? textBaseline,
    double? height,
    Locale? locale,
    Paint? foreground,
    Paint? background,
    List<ui.Shadow>? shadows,
    List<ui.FontFeature>? fontFeatures,
    TextDecoration? decoration,
    Color? decorationColor,
    TextDecorationStyle? decorationStyle,
    double? decorationThickness,
  })> asMap() => const {
        'ABeeZee': GoogleFonts.aBeeZee,
        'Abel': GoogleFonts.abel}
```

Comment: what you don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing a generated code, in the very beginning of the file:

```dart
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT EDIT

// Copyright 2019 The Flutter team. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.
```

This function is defined as:

- Name: `asMap`.
- Scope: top-level (Since it is a static method).
- Return type: `Map<String, TextStyle Function({ ...args })>`.

> It seems we have a function map?

We have a function that returns a map of Strings and Closures. In Dart this is perfectly fine:

```dart
final Map<String, int Function(int, int)> operations = {
  'sum': (int a, int b) => a + b,
  'subtract': (int a, int b) => a - b,
  'multiply': (int a, int b) => a * b,
  'divide': (int a, int b) => a * b
};

operations['sum']!(30, 30); // 60
operations['subtract']!(30, 30); // 0
operations['multiply']!(30, 30); // 900
operations['divide']!(30, 30); // 1
```

In general this is not something we do by raw hands due to type implications (hard to maintain, you can see that it's pretty confusing + it's pretty easy to lost track of type definitions and, consequently, all intellisense features). So that's why this is being done through code generation.

And in this particular case, we are generating a map, like this example below:

```dart
class Arithmetic {
  static int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
  }
  static int subtract(int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
  }
  static int multiply(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
  }
  static int divide(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
  }
  static Map<String, int Function(int, int)> asMap() {
    const Map<String, int Function(int, int)> operationsAsMap = {
      'sum': sum,
      'subtract': subtract,
      'multiply': multiply,
      'divide': divide
    };
    return operationsAsMap;
  }
}
```

> asMap() has a arrow function?

No, the `asMap()` implementation is using an arrow function, which is an alias for:

```dart
// This is a shorthand...
static Map<...> asMap() => const { ... };

// For this:
static Map<...> asMap() {
  return const { ... };
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. It's very clearly explanation and give me big help!